# Documentation for leg_detector

Tags: ros, leg-detector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was looking for the documentation of leg_detector similar to face_detector.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236168/documentation-for-leg_detector/) by [srinimd2005](https://answers.ros.org/users/27084/srinimd2005/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The maintainer is fairly lazy, but he did put some documentation on [the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/leg_detector)

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [srinimd2005](https://answers.ros.org/users/27084/srinimd2005/) on 2016-06-06**:
Thanks for the reply. Yeah I had seen that before. The problem is if I pass the laserscan data to the subscribed topic I am not getting any data out from the published topics. No data. I would like to know how to initialize the package. How to visualize the output data in rviz.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2016-06-06**:
Are you echoing the PositionMeasurement topics and visualizing the markers?

**Comment by [srinimd2005](https://answers.ros.org/users/27084/srinimd2005/) on 2016-06-07**:
Yeah I am echoing the PositionMeasurement topic and Visualizing the markers. But I find no data coming out from it. By the way I forgot to mention my version of ROS. I am using ROS-Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Using Freenect to interface kinect and depth-to-laserscan to feed the leg detector input.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-06-07**:
Did you just try the provided launch-file trained_leg_detector.yaml? Worked for me with openni2_launch.

**Comment by [srinimd2005](https://answers.ros.org/users/27084/srinimd2005/) on 2016-06-07**:
But openni2_launch is not working for me. It always says no camera detected for me. And yeah I am using the given launch file.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2016-06-07**:
Are all of the topics connected in the rqt_graph?

**Comment by [srinimd2005](https://answers.ros.org/users/27084/srinimd2005/) on 2016-06-07**:
At last I got it to work. I think it is the missing library for opencv. by the way now its running but my rviz keeps on crashing if i subscribe to camera topic.